# is it possible to use Facebook Graph API to get just my own wall posts

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I just want to know if it's possible to do the following:

To display some **wall posts** from **my own facebook account** in a **php web page**, without going through the granting-permission in the user interface level? Because from what I know, you need an access token to use the API, and to get an access token, you need to go through the granting-permission UI. So I am feeling impossible here.

I got my app ID and secret code ready, I just want to know for sure if what I want to implement is even possible to begin with.

Comment: As far as I know you will need permissions to access wall posts

Comment: so, it's impossible for what i want to do?

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you could change your privacy permissions so that your wall is completely public. The API is then able to access public information without being granted user authorization.

Answer (score 0):

I was also searching  the same, as I want to implement it in my project. Now I've got the answer of this. **Yes, you can get posts as well as comments from your wall**. If you want more details about same, comment below mentioning my name. :)